# Component not updating/re-rendering after change in an array state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The component is not rerendering after the deletion of an element in the state but the state does change.
In the component, you can add an element in the array (which is a state) through form, see all the elements in the array, and delete it from the state using the button. So after deleting an element that is in the state, the component does not rerender. Following is the code of the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Typography,
  IconButton,
  Button,
  TextField,
  Paper,
} from '@mui/material';
import {
  CancelOutlined,
  AddBoxOutlined,
  VisibilityOutlined,
  VisibilityOffOutlined,
} from '@mui/icons-material';

export default function Test1() {
  const [subNames, setSubNames] = useState([]);
  const [subName, setSubName] = useState('');
  const [showSubForm, setShowSubForm] = useState(false);

  const onSubNameChange = (e) => {
    setSubName(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubNameSubmit = () => {
    if (!subName) return alert('Enter name!');

    setSubNames((prev) => prev.concat({ name: subName }));
    setShowSubForm(false);
    setSubName('');
  };

  const subForm = (
    <>
      <div
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <TextField
          label='Sub Todo Name'
          onChange={onSubNameChange}
          name='subTodoName'
          value={subName}
          size='small'
          variant='outlined'
          fullWidth
        />
        <IconButton onClick={onSubNameSubmit}>
          <AddBoxOutlined color='primary' />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      <br />
    </>
  );

  const onDelete = (position, e) => {
    let arr = subNames;

    arr.splice(position, 1);

    setSubNames(arr);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      {subNames.map((item, key) => (
        <Paper
          key={key}
          sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
            margin: 'auto',
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 10,
            borderRadius: '10px',
          }}
          elevation={3}>
          <div sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Typography variant='body1'>
              <b>Sub Todo-{key + 1}:</b>
            </Typography>
            &nbsp;
            <Typography variant='body1'>{item?.name}</Typography>
          </div>
          <IconButton onClick={(e) => onDelete(key, e)}>
            <CancelOutlined color='primary' />
          </IconButton>
        </Paper>
      ))}
      <br />
      {showSubForm && subForm}
      <div>
        {showSubForm && (
          <Button
            variant='contained'
            sx={{ float: 'right' }}
            color='primary'
            size='small'
            startIcon={<VisibilityOffOutlined />}
            onClick={() => setShowSubForm(false)}>
            Add sub todo item
          </Button>
        )}
        {!showSubForm && (
          <Button
            variant='contained'
            sx={{ float: 'right' }}
            onClick={() => setShowSubForm(true)}
            color='primary'
            size='small'
            startIcon={<VisibilityOutlined />}>
            Add sub todo item
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

React won't update the DOM every time you give the same `state` to a `setState`. For primitive values like `Number`, `String`, and `Boolean`, it's obvious to know whether we are giving a different value or not.

For referenced values like `Object` and `Array` on the other hand, changing their `content` doesn't flag them as different. It should be a different memory `reference`. See your commented code to understand what you are doing wrong:

```js
let arr = subNames;      // does a reference copy, means arr === subNames
arr.splice(position, 1); // changes its content, but still arr === subNames
setSubNames(arr);        // at this point it's like nothing has changed
```

A solution could be the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which will create a copy of your existing array but on a new memory `reference`, like so:

```js
let arr = [...subNames]; // creates a copy of subNames on a new reference
arr.splice(position, 1); // updates the content of the newly created array 
setSubNames(arr);        // new reference is given to setSubNames
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking to update the reference of their `Object` like @YoussoufOumar suggested for arrays, it is easily done by the following:

```js
const [yourObject, setYourObject] = useState<Object>({});

let obj = {...yourObject}; // creates a copy of yourObject on a new reference
obj.prop = 'a new value';  // updates the content of the newly created object
setYourObject(obj);        // new reference is given to setSubNames
```