# React view doesn't update when add a new item to a nested state array/object with Immer.js

Tags: reactjs, state, immer.js

Problem: react view is not updated

I have a state that has the following composition:

```
[
  {
    date: "12/10/2022",
    data: [
      { id: "1", title_tax: "tax number one" },
      { id: "2", title_tax: "tax number two" },
    ],
  },
  {
    date: "13/10/2022",
    data: [{ id: "3", title_tax: "tax number three" }],
  },
];
```

the data object is an array that stores more objects, this is usually where we add more items. The process of adding items to the context is fine and they are added correctly, but the user view does not update these new items.

In my component I have an array (cardsHistory) that basically receives the state I showed and then creates the visualization. I don't have any exceptions or anything, I'm just looking for a way to fix this.

```
interface IProps {
  cardsHistory: IPropsHistoryCard[];
  loadMoreHistories: () => void;
  isData: boolean;
}

function ScrollHistory({ cardsHistory, loadMoreHistories, isData }: IProps) {
  const histories: IPropsHistoryCard[] = cardsHistory;
  console.log(histories);
  return (
    <InfiniteScroll pageStart={1} loadMore={loadMoreHistories} hasMore={isData}>
      {histories && histories?.length > 0 ? (
        histories.map((x: IPropsHistoryCard) => (
          <HistoryCard key={x.date} date={x.date} data={x.data} />
        ))
      ) : (
        <Typography>No history to display</Typography>
      )}
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
}

export default ScrollHistory;
```

just in case when i recieve a new item I'm using immer produce from immer

```
case DashboardActionTypes.addHistory:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        const newElement: IProcess = payload;
        const dayIncluded = new Date(
          newElement.startDateTime,
        ).toLocaleDateString();

        const processElement: IProcess[] = [];
        processElement.push(newElement);

        if (draft.history.length === 0) {
          const historyElement: IPropsHistoryCard = {
            date: dayIncluded,
            data: processElement,
          };
          draft.history.push(historyElement);
        } else {
          const index = draft.history
            .map((object) => object.date)
            .indexOf(dayIncluded);
          if (index < 0) {
            const historyElement: IPropsHistoryCard = {
              date: dayIncluded,
              data: processElement,
            };
            draft.history.push(historyElement);
          } else {
            const isInArray = draft.history[index].data.find(
              (element) => element.id === newElement.id,
            );
            if (isInArray === undefined)
              draft.history[index].data.push(newElement);
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: You can't modify the state directly in react. You have two create a new object every time you want to change t

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I'm using immer for create the new state when i recive a new item

Comment: Found related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185474/component-not-re-rendering-after-change-in-an-array-state-in-react

Comment: @CoolLife you should probably show how the items are getting added ....

Comment: @KcH I just edited my question

Answer (score 2):

React does not perform a deep-check on the props, but just a shallow one. So if the outher most object does not change `React` will bail out from re-rendering your component.

Any state update in react must change the outher most object to be effective so you cannot apped to the array, you have to replace it with a new one.

```js
newArray = [...oldArray, newItem]
```

I avoid strange side effets in React all object shall be immutable, therefore do not mutate objects (unless they are explicitly not meant to affect a component rendering).

There are some [helpers](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/update.html) available to deal with it.

Comment: thanks I understand the concept, I checked it but I'm using immer that produces a new state every time I change the current one, in theory it should be almost the same.

Comment: I see, I edited your question to disambiguate. Silly question, have you checked there are no duplicate keys, they may lead to strange rendering behaviours? Furthermore you are discussing about the `data` field so we need code for the `HistoryCard` component.